# How to Play with particular group using Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

Ansible version: 2.1.0

My ansible hosts file is:

```
[PM]
xyz.example.com ansible_connection=ssh

[ND]
pqr.example.com ansible_connection=ssh

[CM]
xyz.example.com ansible_connection=ssh
pqr.example.com ansible_connection=ssh
```

And playbook is:

```
- hosts: PM:ND:CM
   remote_user: root
   tasks:
    {some thing}

- hosts: PM
   remote_user: root
   tasks:
    {some thing}

 - hosts: ND
   remote_user: root
   tasks:
    {some thing}

- hosts: CM
   remote_user: root
   tasks:
    {some thing}
```

And I am running playbook with the following command:

```
ansible-playbook --limit 'PM' akana-installation.yml
```

But still the playbook is playing with all hosts, it means

```
Play 'PM:ND:CM'
Play 'PM'
Play 'ND'
Play 'CM'
```

those all plays are playing. Please help me to resolve this.

What I need is: **While executing playbook I will give group name, that only group should play**, so please let me know is there any other way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Original question was: *--limit option is not working*

By calling `ansible-playbook --limit 'PM' akana-installation.yml` you tell ansible to limit servers to the hosts that are in PM group.
In your case it will be `xyz.example.com`.
Keep in mind that if you have this server in several groups, as you do, it will still be a member of that groups.
Your limited inventory will become:

```
[PM]
xyz.example.com ansible_connection=ssh

[ND]

[CM]
xyz.example.com ansible_connection=ssh
```

And ansible-playbook will execute every play in your playbook that is applicable for xyz.example.com.
In your case:

```
Play 'PM:ND:CM'
[xyz.example.com]
Play 'PM'
[xyz.example.com]
Play 'ND'
skipping: no hosts matched
Play 'CM'
[xyz.example.com]
```

Comment: Yes, you are right that's what happening to me. But I want to play with particular group hosts, how can I achieve this?

Comment: @KishoreReddy, this is not how thing works in ansible. You can limit hosts (as you do with `--limit` switch), but it will not limit plays. If you want to limit plays, consider separating them to different playbooks and include them into the main playbook (see [example](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#top-level-playbooks-are-separated-by-role): site.yml and webservers.yml). Or use tags.

Answer (score 3):

Create dir for playbook files:

```
mkdir playbooks
```

Split your playbooks into separate files, eg. playbooks/pm.yml:

```
- hosts: PM
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  {some thing}
```

Create file all.yml

```
- hosts: PM:ND:CM
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  {some thing}

- include: playbooks/pm.yml
- include: playbooks/nd.yml
- include: playbooks/cm.yml
```

Now You have separate logic and You can play all with command:

```
ansible-playbook all.yml
```

or run separate command:

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/pm.yml
```

or

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/nd.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to Add on to the previous answer.  And I apologize if I misunderstood your question, but your example playbook, had no descriptions.

**Cleaning up skipped hosts:**
Group 'ND' will (as stated above) not match any hosts.  And if you want to remove the output from the play, you would have to use a Callback plugin.  I use the following [Gist](https://gist.github.com/cThrice/f78d65382b80ad89a38d838d9576798a):

**Another way to limit:**
To limit in the way you are asking to, you will need to use [TAGS](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_tags.html).  This will allow you to limit by play (which is what you seem to want to do) instead of by host lists.

To do this, add a tag to the play:

```
...
- hosts: PM
  remote_user: root
  tags: pmtag
  tasks:
    {some thing}
```

Then run the playbook with the new tag excluded or included depending on your needs.

```
ansible-playbook --limit 'PM' akana-installation.yml --tags pmtag
```

This will ensure that only hosts in PM run only plays tagged with pmtag.